# Proper way move register values in assembly from one location to another

Tags: c++, assembly, struct, mov, eip

I'm currently having some unexplained register issues which I can't figure my guess is I'm moving registers improperly from one register to another one.

I'm trying to get the value of `EDX` into a `test.myEDX` which mostly always puts the wrong value of `EDX` into `test.myEDX`, but part of that `EDX` value seems right which is very strange some kind of Hi/Lo Bits issues I assume.

Let me explain what I'm trying to do.
First I hook a location in memory which contains some arbitrary assembly code.

I hook it by placing a hardware breakpoint at that location then I can see all the register values at that location in time.
Now I made a simple program that everytime the cpu goes into that breakpointed location I put the `EDX` value into a struct in C++.
As far as i am aware nothing should modify the `EDX` register while I am putting it into the struct unless putting values into the struct modifies the `EDX` which I tested isn't the case, I tested by moving the `EDX` first into `EAX` then passing `EAX` into struct which should have the same value as `EDX` and it's still wrong maybe `EAX` is used as well when putting data into the struct? I didn't go further then that in testing all registers to find which one isn't used, doubt that's even the problem anyways.

Another thing to take into consideration to actually do any operations like putting `EDX` into the struct I have to make in C++ the current `EIP` go into my naked function, I know from previously doing this stuff that naked functions don't modify any registers at all, they are simply used as a way to extend the current asm code at that EIP into much larger asm code without any trash that C++ would add when going into subroutines.

I also use `PUSHAD` and `PUSHFD` to restore previously set register values when I finish dumping `EDX` into struct it's all in a safe environment (as long as I don't use `PUSH/POP`'s incorrectly of course) before I call `POPFD` then `POPAD`

I barely know any ASM but from looking at many examples I never see registers moved like this. (which obviously wouldn't make any sense to duplicate a register, but even the same register moved into 2 different addresses one after the one I haven't seen that).

```
MOV EBX, EDX
MOV ECX, EDX
```

But in fact I see something like this (which I thought was my problem why it wasn't working), (it wasn't, I am still clueless what I am doing wrong)

```
MOV EBX, EDX 
MOV EAX, EDX //Theory: in order to move EDX a second time into ECX, I must not move EDX directly into ECX.
MOV ECX, EAX
```

I don't see any difference except now `EAX` is lost, but I still figured I have to re-route every multiple moving of the same register to multiple locations by moving it over and over before actually moving to the original location, silly but that's what I thought you had to do I still think this is the proper way to this job.
Either way this still hasn't helped me I still get wrong values.

I think either those option's `AL` `BL` registers screw up `EDX` or maybe `TEST` or `JE` messes it up I can't really tell, I pasted this code into OllyDBG and seems like nothing modified `EDX` mystery why `EDX` is wrong, Maybe the address updates it's value too slow? since it's based on RAM speed which doesn't sync up with CPU speed (all stupid theories of course).

Anyways that's about everything I can explain here is the code.

```
struct TestStruct {
  int myEDX;
  int mySetEDX;
} test;

extern bool optionOne = false;
extern bool optionTwo = false;
DWORD gotoDumpBackAddress = 0x40012345;

void __declspec( naked ) dump(void) {
    __asm {
        PUSHAD
        PUSHFD
        XOR EAX, EAX //zero EAX, used below as AL (optionOne)
        XOR EBX, EBX //zero EBX, used below as BL (optionTwo)
        MOV AL, optionOne //optionOne set
        MOV BL, optionTwo //optionTwo set

        TEST EAX, EAX //Tests if optionOne equals == 0, then je will be equal.
        je gotoOptionOne //Jumps if optionOne equals 0.
        TEST EBX, EBX //Tests if optionTwo equals == 0, then je will be equal.
        je gotoOptionTwo  //Jumps if optionTwo equals 0.

gotoOptionOne:
//This the default case (improper value in EDX..., I could just use address at [ESI+0x2] which is old EDX, which is risky since it's delayed (outdated)
            MOV DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+0x2], EDX //(normal operation)
            MOV test.myEDX, EDX //Stores freshest EDX to test.myEDX (wrong EDX value)
            JMP finish  //Clear temporary used registers and go back to next asm code

//Special case. (works mostly properly)
//Thing is EDX gets updated very frequently, Causes no side-effect only because
//[ESI+0x2] gets updated in a different location as well a bit later to renew the value.
//So it's not even noticeable, but when I run this at it's peak speeds, you start to see the flickering effect, which isn't normal, if I run peak speeds without hook.
//I eliminated the problem that the hook could cause the flicker effect since after
//I call a empty naked Hook with just return address to same location and disable hook
//Then re-enable hook and repeat step above (no flicker occurs).
gotoOptionTwo:
            //MOV DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+0x2], EDX //(normal operation), omitted
            MOV EAX, DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+0x2] //Old EDX, but atleast it's correct.
            MOV test.myEDX, EAX //Stores old EDX into struct test.myEDX
            MOV EAX, test.mySetEDX //Replace old EDX with what I wish it should be.
            MOV DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+0x2], EAX //nySetEDX into what EDX should of did.
            JMP finish //Clear temporary used registers and go back to next asm code
finish:
        POPFD
        POPAD

        JMP gotoDumpBackAddress //return to starting location before dump + 1.

    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Okay I haven't explained how I test this code out.

I'm not going to explain how I do the Hardware breakpoint, I don't want this method to be public on the internet, for my own security reasons in the future.
But it works by calling another DLL which communicates with a system driver.

But this should explain how I test it.

I run in a different thread in this DLL Injection.

```
void diffThread() {
  while(1) {
    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD0)) {
      optionOne != optionOne;
      Sleep(1000);
    }

    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD1)) {
      optionTwo != optionTwo;
      Sleep(1000);
    }

    Sleep(10);
  }
}

bool __stdcall DllMain(HINSTANCE hInst,DWORD uReason,void* lpReserved)
{
    if(uReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        CreateThread(NULL,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&diffThread,0 ,NULL,NULL); 
    }
    else if(uReason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH) 
    { 
        ExitThread(0);
    } 
    return true;
}
```

Comment: On which operating system are you coding? With which compiler? Why do you code in assembly?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You don't 'move registers ... from one location to another', and you don't 'move registers ... from one register to another' either. You move *values* from one register or location to another register or location. I suspect your confusion about the terminology is at the root of your confusion about this question. Try again. You also need to take into account that calling C functions may corrupt any register, and that it's probably up to you to preserve their values across function calls.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is. Is it "Can I move a register from EAX to EDX by using `MOV EAX, EDX`?", then yes, of course you can. The reason you typically don't see this in examples or compiled code is that moving from one register to another is typically avoided, just use the value in `EAX`. I don't understand even a little bit about what your code dodes (it's awfully complicated).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Microsfot Visual C++ 2010 Express compiler unmanaged

Comment: @MatsPetersson my code is just a simple kind of Memory Modifier but instead of modifying memory I modify register values at certain asm code breakpoints with my own.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. In your code example there seem to be many uninitiliazed values being used. I read it now several times and still don't get what you really are trying to do. Actually I'm surprised that this even compiles.

Comment: @Devolus if you mean the zero'd EAX EBX those are filled by 16 bit versions of themselves I zero it to make sure it doesn't corrupt the `TEST` check, just being sure, even if it's useless code, all the register values should be filled up at the HW Breakpoint since the naked function is called in the middle of some deep code execution in the main program (not this injected dll).

Comment: Without reading too much into this, when you say "hi/low bit issues"... are you talking about endianness?  Do you understand what little endian is?

Comment: @SoapBox I guess so, I know about endianness in programming I don't think this exists in assembly though, what I ment is 16 bit registers set either the hi or lo of the equivialent 32 bit register EAX and EBX. AL sets the LOW of the EAX and BL sets the LOW of the EBX, I could of used AL AH I guess.. But I don't know how to TEST against it.

Comment: I think it's prudent to explicitly say, than *mov* instruction is misleadingly named. It does not "move", it copies value, does assignment. A simple assignment in C code might become a single *mov* assembly instruction (or two, if it is memory-to-memory copy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay honestly this is wrong on so many levels, I mean the code itself.
What you are trying to do is to force your way into C territory telling the compiler to back off and you do your own thing by handwriting the code. This may come handy sometimes but you have to keep in mind that you also loose some C features especially things that are done for you automatically and as far as I know the Microsoft compile just doesnt like you messing around in inline assmebly ( don't get me wrong the MASM compiler is great but it just doesn't play along well with the C compiler )

```
// doing this is not the best since the compiler may
// do some nasty stuff like aligning the struct that
// you have to take watch out for in asm
struct TestStruct {
      int myEDX;
      int mySetEDX;
    } test;

extern bool optionOne = false;
extern bool optionTwo = false;
DWORD gotoDumpBackAddress = 0x40012345; // static memory address? this should fail like instantly, I dont really know what this is supposed to be

void __declspec( naked ) dump(void) {
    __asm {
        PUSHAD // you shouldn't normally push all registers only the ones you actually used!
        PUSHFD
        XOR EAX, EAX // this is how you zero out but honestly you can use EAX's low and high parts as 2 16bit regsiters instead of using 2 32bits for 2 bits of data
        XOR EBX, EBX
        MOV AL, optionOne //optionOne set
        MOV BL, optionTwo //optionTwo set

        TEST EAX, EAX // This check is meaning less because if gotoOptionTwo is false you move on regardless of gotoOpeionOne's value
        je gotoOptionOne
        TEST EBX, EBX // This test should always be true isn't it?
        je gotoOptionTwo

gotoOptionOne:
// Assuming that ESI is coming from the system as you said that there is a
// breakpoint that invokes this code, do you even have access to that part of the memory?
            MOV DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+0x2], EDX
            MOV test.myEDX, EDX // this is just a C idom 'struct' this doesnt really exist in ASM
            JMP finish

gotoOptionTwo:
            MOV EAX, DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+0x2]
            MOV test.myEDX, EAX
            MOV EAX, test.mySetEDX
            MOV DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+0x2], EAX
            JMP finish
finish:
        POPFD
        POPAD

        JMP gotoDumpBackAddress //return to starting location before dump + 1.

    }
}
```

So to answer your question,

I think the biggest problem here is this line

```
MOV test.myEDX, EDX
```

Generally in ASM there is no such thing as a scope, like you're telling it to get you a value of myEDX from test which means get the pointer to the value test and then get the value by the pointer. It may work but it's up to the C compiler to help you out.

So normally you would need to get a pointer and use that to move the data like

```
LEA ecx,test // get the address of test
MOV DWORD PTR[ecx],edx // use that address to move the data into the struct
```

Now you are telling it to put that data into the struct, however this makes some assumptions, like here we know that the first element is the one we want to put the data into ( myEDX ) and we assume that a DWORD is the same as an int in C ( on Windows it usually is ) but again assumptions are bad!

Comment: EBX check isn't always true, if I set optionTwo to true it jumps to that bottom label code fine. Okay I'll make both int's in the struct into DWORD's, i'll remember that LEA trick, but the struct does work for setting the value just fine using whatever value I want to put into the struct it updates in that ESI+0x2 address just fine. I tried without struct for retieving the value and still bad values  pastebin.com/YhByZ62D I'm back to thinking it's the EDX. Static return address works because this is a dll injection (this dll is inside the app so the addresses are correct)

Comment: Doubt DWORD will ever change from 4 bytes to something else, Also, `optionOne` and `optionTwo` are C++ `bool`'s they only work with 16 bit registers. Could it be because I'm accessing the EDX output from another thread while the EDX output is getting written simultaneously and it doesn't finish the writing of the output properly?

Comment: Depends on what you do but most ASM operations are atomic so there is no thing as half written register its either done or not done. It could be wrong if you forcefully break out of something. Aren't you supposed to move out of the memory location? MOV DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+0x2], EDX so this should be the other way around? Because that is a move EDX into the memory location.

Comment: that memory location makes the change happen in real-time, the register EDX is what the change should be next normally, I'm trying to filter it before it makes the changes, I also use this to know what EDX is so I know the proper path to take before I filter it, this also makes randomly reading memory at some interval, 100% accurate, since this gets perfect time memory has to be edited.

Comment: Okay then I have no idea what's going on try to write a question that can be answered, there are too many unknown parts of this question. Like I dont really get how it is supposed to work...

Comment: This is Code injection which gets re-injected everytime a HW Breakpoint is triggered (yeah it should slow down performance (it doesn't though) by doing this, but it's the only way I know of to do this, I cannot patch the application, it will result in checksums issue. I will keep trying and write back if I figure some solution out. Yes I agree the question is all over the place and misleading title too, I just don't know whats causing it.

Comment: At least this question is not the average "My 16 bit input code doesn't work". ;)

Comment: Haha, Hey I did some more testing, whenever I read EDX for the first time, it's correct, reading the next EDX (after doing a normal change) value always has a offset which is why the value is bad.. seems these offsets are not random and have some kind of repeating pattern, I don't know where these EDX patterns come from. Here is some information url: http://pastebin.com/ziCcCHrm I actually see a fix to this just round down to nearest thousand should fix this. Seems EDX value was just misunderstood by me, it's extremely precise, I thought it went up by 1000 increments, should I just delete q?

Comment: `EDX = (EDX - (EDX % 1000));` fixed it, completely off topic but yeah sorry guys I made a question without enough information and there was no way for you guys to help me out

Comment: So if its been fixed accept someones answer then so people will know that you resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Some things that I noticed in your code:

First of all, I don't think that you really need to do the `pushad` and `pushfd` You are only using one register really, because `ebx` wouldn't even be needed, and `eax` is not considered by the compiler to be preserved anyway.

```
    XOR EAX, EAX //zero EAX, used below as AL (optionOne)
    MOV AL, optionOne //optionOne set
    TEST EAX, EAX //Tests if optionOne equals == 0, then je will be equal.
    je gotoOptionOne //Jumps if optionOne equals 0.

    MOV AL, optionTwo //optionTwo set
    TEST EAX, EAX //Tests if optionTwo equals == 0, then je will be equal.
    je gotoOptionTwo  //Jumps if optionTwo equals 0.
```

Your assumption

```
 MOV EBX, EDX 
 MOV EAX, EDX //Theory: in order to move EDX a second time into ECX, I must not move EDX directly into ECX.
 MOV ECX, EAX
```

is simply wrong. You can move the same register as often as you like, there is no limitation. The only thing that **MIGHT** be of consideration is when you are looking for maximum performance because of the instruction scheduling, but this is an entirely different issue and doesn't apply here anyway.

So simply doing

```
 MOV EBX, EDX 
 MOV ECX, EDX
```

would be fine.

You are using `ESI` but it is nowhere initialized. Maybe this is correct, as I don't really understand what your code is supposed to do.

The you are using the variable `test` here

```
MOV test.myEDX, EAX
MOV EAX, test.mySetEDX
```

but this variable isn't even declared, so where should the compiler know it's address from? And for using it as an offset then you would have to use a register as the base address.

Comment: I thought the `TestStruct` called `test` is automatically declared (maybe the struct is giving me the wrong values I see), how would I declare it globally?, I thought the structure is implicitly initialized if you named it.

Comment: The struct is not declared, it is just defined, so that the compiler knows it's layout. You have to give it an address to actually use it.

Comment: Yeah but it works just fine when I initialize it's members even though it's just a layout I guess? I see it right now similarly to `char test[1];` right now (automatic setter), without new() or malloc.. it's not a class after all.